# Where is the Octave executable in Linux Mint?

Tags: jupyter, conda, octave

Where does the executable for Octave live? Specifically, what folder?
I'm trying to get Octave to work in Miniconda with Jupyter lab.

Comment: type `which octave` in your linux terminal to see what file it references

Comment: Check to see if Octave is even installed! Linux distributions contain many, many software packages, and not all are installed by default. Octave is not installed by default on any Linux distro that I know of. So you may need to install it first.

Comment: It's already installed and it works.